# Can etcd be used as message bus like Kafka with single producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, etcd

Etcd provides a distributed replicated key value store. Assume I have 4 cluster etcd setup. Say suppose I have just one producer, can etcd be used to mimic message queue among different key events. Say we have the following four events generated by the producer: 1. Add:key1, value1 2. Add: key2, value2 3. Modify: key2, value3 4. Modify: key1, value4. Will all the consumers see these events in the same order?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use etcd as queue and maintain order of events.
https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/api.html#atomically-creating-in-order-keys

Kafka suits this usecase much better. To maintain order you need to use Topic with single partition.

You might want to think about some of features Kafka supports, how to deal when consumers go offline and come back ? Consumer groups?